# half fixed, half dynamic array in C

Tags: c, arrays

Is there a way initialize half fixed, half dynamic sized string array? How?

Example:

```
char **p[2];

/*Memory allocation here*/

strcpy(p[0][0], "foo");
strcpy(p[0][1], "bar");
strcpy(p[1][0], "baz");  
strcpy(p[1][1], "qux");
```

Comment: Yes, there is a way.

Comment: When you say 'initialize', do you mean 'initialize as part of the variable definition' or 'create a data structure with multiple statements after the variable definition'?  The latter is what you illustrate, but isn't what 'initialization' means in C.  Also, which is the variable part, and which is the fixed part in your view?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Actually is variable definition in example true i don't know either. But i mean how to initialize and how to allocate memory? I hope im clear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, there is a way.

```
p[0] = malloc(sizeof(char *) * 2); //Two pointers in p[0]
p[1] = malloc(sizeof(char *) * 2); //Two pointers in p[1]

p[0][0] = malloc(sizeof(char) * 4); //4 bytes in p[0][0]
p[0][1] = malloc(sizeof(char) * 4);
p[1][0] = malloc(sizeof(char) * 4);
p[1][1] = malloc(sizeof(char) * 4);
```

Comment: `sizeof (char)` is 1 by definition.

Comment: In that case you're better off writing `p[0][0] = malloc(4 * sizeof *p[0][0])` anyway, because that works with any type.

Answer (score 2):

Using compound literals from C99, you can initialize the variable `p` as shown:

```
extern char **p[2];

char **p[2] = (char **[2]){
    (char *[2]){ "foo", "bar" },
    (char *[2]){ "baz", "qux" },
};
```

The `extern` line would go in a header; the rest would go in the source file that defines `p`.  Alternatively, you can do without the `extern` line and make it `static char **p[2] = …`, which is probably better because `p` is a lousy name for a global variable.

The `(char **[2]){ … }` part is a compound literal of the same type as `p`; inside, it has two `(char *[2]){ … }` units, an array of 2 `char *`.

The strings that are pointed to are not modifiable; if they must be modifiable, you have to work harder (but it can be done).

This test code demonstrates that it works:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 2; j++)
            printf("[%s]", p[i][j]);
        putchar('\n');
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
[foo][bar]
[baz][qux]
```

If you want to decide how long the array of pointers to arrays of two strings should be at run-time (so you can add `{ "abc", "def" }` and `{ "pqr", "xyz" }` at some point), then you need to go in for dynamic memory allocation, but you probably won't have a fixed list of strings to start with.  You'll be reading them from a (configuration?) file, or something similar.

Comment: God bless object oriented programming.